# can't login to my account

Tags: login

after typing my password and press enter 
it takes me back to the page and ask to me to enter my password again 
I can login as a guest 
and am able to login in the terminal ( ctrl+alt+F1 )

but not with the graphical interface

Comment: Try this: log into the virtual terminal at Ctrl+Alt+F1, and type `mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.old` and then try to login to the GUI. If it doesn't work at first, try a reboot. If it doesn't work, do `tail /var/log/lightdm` and tell us what the output is.

Comment: both doesn't work :S

Comment: What is the output when you did `mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.old`? And for the second command, I'm sorry, it should be `sudo tail /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`. Give us the output of this command.

Comment: for the first command it says No such file or directory
and the same for the 2nd command as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 1):

When logged in to the terminal look for a file in home directory called .Xauthority (hidden file) use `ls -al`. If the file is owned by root use `sudo chown <user>:<user> .Xauthority`.

Comment: what does the command `chown user:user .Xauthority` do?

Comment: it says no such file or directory

Comment: It changes the ownership of the file to your group and your user. By default every user has their own group that is named after their username. Every file has a group that owns it as well as a user. To learn more check out `man chown`. Is the .Xauthority file owned by root?

Comment: i am nor sure how to check that :)

Comment: When in the home directory run `ls -al` you should see a file `-rw-------  1 myuser myuser   179 Jun 11 14:56 .Xauthority`, if instead of saying "myuser" it says "root" then run the chown command. I should note Alaa's method should work just as well, if it is easier for you. Instead of changing the ownership it will force the creation of a new file with the correct ownership.

Comment: no it's saying baja baja < which is my username 

but there's a problem 

in the last 2 lines it says 
.xsession-errors
.xsession-errors.old

Comment: Those files are almost always there, but they are worth a look, maybe they will give a clue to the problem. I would try Alaa's suggestion next.

Comment: tried that one but didn't work :'(

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem with the keyboard/language settings? It seems the initial installation determines the layout for the login page, and even if you have changed the default keyboard layout, the login keyboard layout does not change with it. This happened to me and to [Vic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130064/lightdm-allows-only-russian-keyboard-layout-at-login). Since 11.10 lightDM is used and it is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64914/how-can-i-change-the-keyboard-layout-in-the-login-screen). For 12.04 the procedure is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171603/how-to-add-a-keyboard-layout-to-the-login-screen), but it seems to be [buggy](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm-gtk-greeter/+bug/990214).

Comment: but how can the terminal log in work then?

Comment: the gui login uses its own keyboard settings, independently of the cli which is in sync with the rest of Ubuntu