# Cannot log in ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: login

I just started to upgrade ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. Installation was not successful. After restart I can see the login page with my username and guest but when I fill login details nothing happens. Same login window appears again. Please help.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/306953/cant-login-to-my-account

Answer (score 0):

ATL+CTRL+F1

```
$ sudo service lightdm restart
```

ALT+CTRL+F7 => try to login

if it still frozen => ALT+CTRL+F1

```
$ sudo apt-get purge lightdm
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

Comment: Already done but not working.

Comment: Can't start internet so update don't work.